# How can I set up a dynamic import from a Google Doc file to a cell in a Google sheet?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, google-apps-script, import

I have a project going which requires a lot of Google Sheet-based analysis on content from a Google Doc (imagine an article being imported in a particular cell, from which I cut and present each paragraph in separate columns and do various analyses on their content).

The problem is that both the Google Doc and the Sheet are being worked on simultaneously. What I want to do is save myself the trouble of having to manually copy and paste the text from the Doc file each time I want to carry out analysis, and instead just have it automatically update with the latest text content.

I'm familiar with IMPORT functions already, but they all require tabled content as far as I'm aware, I can't just use IMPORTRANGE, IMPORTDATA or IMPORTHTML with the Google doc ID.

I asked this question over on Google and they confirmed it would require some custom scripting. My question is whether it would be a fairly simple script, or even if the script has already been written by someone?

I basically just need to import an entire text into one cell dynamically, is it possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome. This site is for specific programming questions but this question looks to be too broad and it's asking for an external resource which is off-topic here. To learn about how this site works take the [tour] and to learn the basics about asking questions here checkout [ask].

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for your response. Could you possibly direct me to a better place to ask this question?

Comment: Start reading https://www.google.com/script/start